# Bootstrap 2.3.2: Layout is narrower using NuGet package compared with CDN

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, nuget, cdn

I need to change an ASP.NET Webforms site to NOT pull Twitter Bootstrap from a CDN but rather from the sites web server. I have installed the NuGet package for version 2.3.2 and changed the links in the MasterPages from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/content/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
```

I have changed bootstrap.min.js to also use the NuGet package copy. Everything works fine, except the site layout is now much narrower, about 50% of the horizontal screen space is now wasted. I cant find anything online that explains this issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the NetCDN/MaxCDN files are quite different from the NuGet packages. Since the formatting of the .min and non-.min are both so different I couldn't diff them to find out what has changed.

As expected these two files are the same (same company):

- http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css
- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css

The content of the [`bootstrap`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/2.3.2) NuGet package is slightly different to the [`Twitter.Bootstrap`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap/2.3.2) package, however they both have the same display name so you might want to check which one you've got.

The generated [source code in the official git repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css) is wildly different to MaxCDN, but very close to the NuGet packages (`bootstrap` just has a different top comment, and `Twitter.Bootstrap` has a different file path for glyphicons).

Microsoft's [bootstrap CDN](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css) has exactly the same content as the `bootstrap` NuGet package.

I tried looking at a unified diff of the two files (just the non-.min ones) you are moving between, but they are just so different I don't know which change has caused this defect you are seeing, and since they are so different you might have more than just one defect caused by switching files. I haven't checked Bower to see what it has.

I know this isn't a solution to your problem, but it explains why you are seeing problems changing from the CDN. I don't know where all these different copies of the files have come from and it is very concerning we've got a mess on our hands.

Comment: My assumption was that bootstrap was bootstrap if it was the same version so I didn't even think about doing a diff...but that seems obvious now. Learning of the fact they can be different is enough of an explanation for my purposes now. It is a great shame that there are differences. I will keeping using the CDN version for the time being. Thanks.